# Is it possible to update card dynamically on Amazon Alexa skill?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am wondering if a card is possible to update through the skill, while the session is still on.

The use case would be, for example, streaming audio and then, after certain timestamp update the related card.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only send [Cards](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html), but they are not editable afterwards. You can neither delete them nor edit them after you sent them.

I think something like this could be done by using [APL](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-overview.html), but only on display-activated devices.

You can suggest the implementation of editable cards [here](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Alexa works on a request-response model, so you can only set a new/updated card when you send out the response from your skill.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot update the cards which are already sent. But remember the latest card will be shown first in the Alexa app. So you can send the updated card as a response to another subsequent  request with a little hint like *”Please check the latest card for the updated details.”*